# Add asp:TableRows to asp:Table after load in the background

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add rows to an ASP table control in a seperate thread. Basically this is what I have so far:

Codebehind:

```
    protected void onLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread obj = new Thread(new ThreadStart(testX));
        obj.IsBackground = true;
        obj.Start();
    }

    void testX()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Table tblOnline = (Table)FindControl("test");
        TableRow r = new TableRow();
        TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
        Label test = new Label();
        test.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        test.Font.Bold = true;
        test.Text = "Rank";
        c1.Controls.Add(test);
        r.Cells.Add(c1);
        tblOnline.Rows.Add(r);
    }
```

My ASPX:

```
<body>
<asp:Table runat="server" id="test"></asp:Table>
</body>
```

When I compile the website, I don't see any row added to the table after 5 seconds. Is this not possible or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you done any debugging to confirm the method is getting hit and creating the table row?

Comment: When you say "I don't see any row added to the table after 5 seconds", how are you expecting to see the new row?  On the client side, or while debugging the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting to see the new row appear on the client side five seconds after rendering, that's not going to happen with this code.  A background thread *on the server* is not going to cause the *client* to change its appearance.

If you want that to happen, you need to initiate the event from the client, with Javascript (if you don't need any server data) or an Ajax call (if you do).  This is itself happening in the background, so you don't need to run a separate thread on the server.

Comment: Thanks, that's the explanation/answer I was looking for. I wasn't sure if this was possible - I had hunch it wasn't but I just needed it confirmed :). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using Threads with ASP.NET will not work the way you are trying.

If what you want is to add a row to a table every 5 seconds, I suggest you using an Timer control:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="tableTest">
</asp:Table>
<asp:Timer ID="timerAddRow" runat="server" OnTick="timerAddRow_Tick" Interval="5000">
</asp:Timer>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void timerAddRow_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    TableRow r = new TableRow();
    TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
    Label test = new Label();
    test.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    test.Font.Bold = true;
    test.Text = "Rank";
    c1.Controls.Add(test);
    r.Cells.Add(c1);
    tableTest.Rows.Add(r);
}
```